# Bash script; optimization of processing speed

Tags: shell-script, performance

I was wondering if there are general guidelines for optimizing Bash scripts.

- For example, it is more *convenient* to write loops than lines of commands, but is it also *faster to process* for the system? Example:

  ```
  for i in a b c; do echo $i; done

  echo a
  echo b
  echo c
  ```
- Sometimes people present different solutions for the same problem. For example, `sed`, `cut`, `awk`, and `echo` are all able to strip digits from a string.
  I was wondering if you can say that the fewer digits code has, the faster it is if you use:

  1. the same command, e.g.

     ```
     STRING=abc.def
     echo ${STRING} | sed 's/.def//g'
     echo ${STRING} | sed '$s/....$//'
     ```
  2. different commands, e.g.

     ```
     STRING=abc.def
     echo ${STRING} | cut -d . -f 1
     echo ${STRING} | sed 's/.def//g'
     ```

Comment: In most cases I would prefer readability over speed.

Comment: a) Yes there is an overhead in using a for loop but it doesn't matter b) try to minimize external commands and just replace things from within bash. And if you have to optimise your shell script you are doing something wrong and should consider using a language with better profiler support.

Comment: Regular expressions are generally less efficient performance wise than any other choice, so if you see a way to do something without one (eg, cut), use that.  Of course, that *may* affect readability if your reading ability is limited to regular expressions ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shells do not do any reorganization of the code they get handed, it is just interpreted one line after the other (nothing else does much sense in a command interpreter). Much of the time spent by the shell goes to lexical analysis/parsing/launching the programs called.

For simple operations (like the ones munging strings in the examples at the end of the question) I'd be surprised if the time to load the programs don't swamp any minuscule speed differences.

The moral of the story is that if you really need more speed, you are better off with a (semi)compiled language like Perl or Python, which is faster to run to start with, in which you can write many of the operations mentioned directly and don't have to call out to external programs, and has the option to invoke external programs or call into optimized C (or whatever) modules to do much of the job. That is the reason why in Fedora the "system administration sugar" (GUIs, essentially) are written in Python: Can add a nice GUI with not too much effort, fast enough for such applications, have direct access to system calls. If that isn't enough speed, grab C++ or C.

But **do not** go there, unless you can *prove* that the performance gain is worth the loss in flexibility and the development time. Shell scripts are not too bad to read, but I shudder when I remember some scripts used to install Ultrix I once tried to decipher. I gave up, too much "shell script optimization" had been applied.

Comment: +1 *but* a lot of people would argue there is more likely to be a *gain* in flexibility and development time using something like python or perl vs. shell, not a loss.  I would say only use a shell script if it's necessitated, or what you are doing involves a copious amount of shell specific commands.

Answer (score 28):

The first rule of optimization is: **don't optimize**. Test first. If the tests show that your program is too slow, look for possible optimizations.

The only way to be sure is to benchmark for your use case. There are some general rules, but they only apply for typical volumes of data in typical applications.

Some general rules which may or may not be true in any particular circumstance:

- For internal processing in the shell, ATT ksh is fastest. If you do a lot of string manipulations, use ATT ksh. Dash comes second; bash, pdksh and zsh lag behind.
- If you need to invoke a shell frequently to perform a very short task each time, dash wins because of its low startup time.
- Starting an external process costs time, so it's faster to have one pipeline with complex pieces than a pipeline in a loop.
- `echo $foo` is slower than `echo "$foo"`, because with no double quotes, it splits `$foo` into words and interprets each word as a filename wildcard pattern. More importantly, that splitting and globbing behavior is rarely desired. So remember to always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions: `"$foo"`, `"$(foo)"`.
- Dedicated tools tend to win over general-purpose tools. For example, tools like `cut` or `head` can be emulated with `sed`, but `sed` will be slower and `awk` will be even slower. Shell string processing is slow, but for short strings it largely beats calling an external program.
- More advanced languages such as Perl, Python, and Ruby often let you write faster algorithms, but they have a significantly higher startup time so they're only worth it for performance for large amounts of data.
- On Linux at least, pipes tend to be faster than temporary files.
- Most uses of shell scripting are around I/O-bound processes, so CPU consumption doesn't matter.

**It's rare that performance is a concern in shell scripts.** The list above is purely indicative; it's perfectly fine to use “slow” methods in most cases as the difference is often a fraction of a percent.

Usually the point of a shell script is to get something done fast. You have to gain a lot from optimization to justify spending extra minutes writing the script.

Comment: While `python` and `ruby` are definitely slower to start, at least on my system, `perl` is as quick to start as `bash` or `ksh`. GNU awk is significantly slower than GNU sed especially in utf-8 locales, but it's not true of all awks and all seds. the ksh93 > dash > pdksh > zsh > bash is not always as clear cut as that. Some shells are better at some things than others, and the winner is not always the same.

Comment: Re *"you have to gain a lot from..."*:   if *"you"* includes the userbase, true.  With shell scripts in popular Linux packages often users collectively waste several orders of magnitude more time than the hasty programmer saves.

Answer (score 4):

> We'll expand here on our globbing example above to illustrate some performance characteristics of the shell script interpreter. Comparing the `bash` and `dash` interpreters for this example where a process is spawned for each of 30,000 files, shows that dash can fork the `wc` processes nearly twice as fast as `bash`

```
bash-4.2$ time dash -c 'for i in *; do wc -l "$i"; done>/dev/null'
real    0m1.238s
user    0m0.309s
sys     0m0.815s


bash-4.2$ time bash -c 'for i in *; do wc -l "$i"; done>/dev/null'
real    0m1.422s
user    0m0.349s
sys     0m0.940s
```

> Comparing the base looping speed by not invoking the `wc` processes, shows that dash's looping is nearly 6 times faster!
>
> ```
> $ time bash -c 'for i in *; do echo "$i">/dev/null; done'
> real    0m1.715s
> user    0m1.459s
> sys     0m0.252s
>
>
>
> $ time dash -c 'for i in *; do echo "$i">/dev/null; done'
> real    0m0.375s
> user    0m0.169s
> sys     0m0.203s
> ```
>
> The looping is still relatively slow in either shell as demonstrated previously, so for scalability we should try and use more functional techniques so iteration is performed in compiled processes.
>
> ```
> $ time find -type f -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=- | tail -n1
>     30000 total
> real    0m0.299s
> user    0m0.072s
> sys     0m0.221s
> ```
>
> The above is by far the most efficient solution and illustrates the point well that one should do as little as possible in shell script and aim just to use it to connect the existing logic available in the rich set of utilities available on a UNIX system.

Stolen From [Common shell script mistakes](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/shell_script_mistakes.html) by Pádraig Brady.

Comment: A generic rule: file descriptor handling also costs, so reduce their count. Instead of `for i in *; do wc -l "$i">/dev/null; done` better do `for i in *; do wc -l "$i"; done>/dev/null`.

Comment: @manatwork it will also null output of `time` cmd

Comment: @manatwork Good... now Please also give me output of without invoking `wc -l`, check i have updated in post your output

Comment: Well, the previous measurements were made on a smaller directory. Now I created one with 30000 files and repeated the tests: http://pastebin.com/pCV6QKp2

Comment: Those benchmarks fail to allow for the different starting times of each shell.  Benchmarks done from *within* each shell would be better.

Answer (score 2):

My quick takes:

- Avoid subshells.

  - Remember that `{ }` (no subshell) can often/sometimes be used instead of `( )` (subshell)
- Use shell built-in functions in favour of external commands.

  - e.g. get the date by calling the shell function `date()` rather than e.g. `/usr/bin/date`, and the same for `printf`
- Use shell variables in favour of calling shell built-ins or commands.

  - e.g. to get current time, if you can get away with querying `$SECONDS` rather than calling `date()`, the former will be faster
- For string manipulation, use variable expansion `${...}` in favour of other alternatives, like calling external commands (`cut`, `tr` etc.)
- When processing text files, if possible, avoid reading line-by-line into variables, and instead use external commands like like `sed`, `tr`, `cut` on the whole file.

  - If you need to read text files to variables for processing the data which includes filtering it (reducing information), instead, try to do the filtering with external commands, on the whole file, then read the filtered (reduced) data into variables.
- If using regex-es, write them carefully, e.g. avoid backtracking.

  - Ill-written regex-es can sometimes be 100x or more worse in performance than an equivalent regex.