# Transforming if statement in case

Tags: shell, scripting, algorithms

I'm currently testing changes in my scripts for performance purposes. Specifically, I want to change `if` to `case` statements.

However, being new to shell programming I'm getting stuck on this type of statement:

```
if [ "$A" == "x" -a "$B" == "y" ] 
    then
        let a=a+1
fi
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
case "$A$B" in
    "x""y") let a=a+1
;;
esac
```

What did I get wrong?

And is it possible to manage a "!=" in case statements? Such as:

```
if [ "$A" == "x" -a "$B" != "y" ] 
then
    let a=a+1
fi
```

Comment: This optimisation may not be worth it if your shell has `[` as a builtin (You can check with `command -V [` which says "[ is a shell builtin". When optimising, specify which shell you want to target for.

Comment: @Kusalananda I edited my post :)

Comment: @Matieu this is a *shell script* so it is slow and inefficient pretty much by definition. What makes you think switching from `if` to `case` will give a non insignificant improvement? Especially when you consider the time you will spend trying to figure out how to do it, then doing it, and then fixing the bugs that your changes introduced.

Comment: @terdon I did some research and found http://www.los-gatos.ca.us/davidbu/faster_sh.html or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67057/bash-script-optimization-of-processing-speed . Some worked and some did not but at the end after few hours I managed to reduce the script execution time by 15%, which is something significant when the script will be executed everyday. Moreover this is my first shell script and by definition it **surely** is **bad** code.

Comment: @Matieu yes, precisely. The answer you linked to states: "The moral of the story is that if you really need more speed, you are better off with a (semi)compiled language like Perl or Python [. . .]" :)

Comment: @terdon True! In the meantime the other link shows that optimizations can be done and unfortunately I can't afford to rewrite my scripts (deadline issue)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `case` example works for me, but note that you are comparing the *concatenation* of `A` and `B`, so the pattern will match also if, say `A` is `xy` and `B` is empty. (I think the double-quotes in the middle are redundant.) `case` only takes a single *word* to compare against the patterns, so you can't compare several variables except by concatenating.

In the standard `test`, or `[` command, the comparison operator is `=`. `==` works in some systems, but not all. Also, combining conditions using `-a` is problematic, at least with conditions like `-n`. (see [this question](/questions/57840/posix-test-and-a)). Better use `if [ "$A" = x ] && [ "$B" = y ] ; then ...`.

As for inverting a `case`, you'd need to come up with a pattern that matches everything but the target string. [`extglob` in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and others allows for matching anything except:

```
case $B in !(y) ) echo not y ;; esac
```

Without it, you'd need to do some more work in inverting the pattern, or use multiple patterns with the first ones matching the string and a later default match doing the actual action.

```
case $B in ??*) echo not y ;; [^y]) echo also not y ;; esac

case $B in y) ;; *) echo still not y ;; esac
```

(no guarantees, especially on the first one. Frankly, the whole idea of doing this seems horrible.)

Anyway, since you mentioned performance reasons, you might consider changing to Perl or Python instead of the shell, not as much because of simple comparisons, but because they'll allow you to do more without calling external programs (like `grep`, `sed`, `cut`, or `jq`). Also, the first rule of performance optimizations: measure the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser I'm starting to understand how it really works. However I don't want the _concatenation_ of the strings but more like if a equals to x AND b equals to y, x and y being preset strings and a & b strings set by the jq command (that parses json files) at the beginning of the script, then do stuff.

Comment: @Matieu, edited, in short, I don't think you can get that.

Comment: @ilkkachu `case $B in ??*) echo not y ;; [^y]) echo also not y ;; esac` will match even when `$B` is `empty`. `case $B in '' | ??* | [!y] ) echo not y ;; esac`

Answer (score 1):

```
#  $A = "x" && $B = "y"
case ${A:--}/${B:--} in 'x/y' ) let a=a+1;; esac

# $A = "x" && $B != "y"
case $A in 'x' ) case $B in '' | ??* | [!y] ) let a=a+1;; esac;; esac
```