# Get the latest entry based on the date in the file

Tags: bash, text-processing

Please see if you could help with below, I have tried few different things but not able to achieve what I am looking for.

userid.txt

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
```

file1.txt

```
AmLogin server1 [03/Feb/2021:00:04:09 -0600] "11.11.11.11 uid=user1,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server1 [03/Feb/2021:00:05:11 -0600] "22.22.22.22 uid=user2,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server1 [03/Feb/2021:00:08:25 -0600] "33.33.33.33 uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
```

file2.txt

```
AmLogin server2 [04/Feb/2021:00:01:09 -0600] "11.11.11.11 uid=user1,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server2 [04/Feb/2021:00:01:11 -0600] "22.22.22.22 uid=user2,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server2 [04/Feb/2021:00:01:25 -0600] "33.33.33.33 uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server2 [04/Feb/2021:00:02:30 -0600] "11.11.11.11 uid=user1,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server2 [04/Feb/2021:00:05:20 -0600] "2.2.2.2 uid=user2,ou=people,dc=company2,dc=com"
AmLogin server5 [07/Feb/2021:00:02:30 -0600] "11.11.11.11 uid=user4,ou=People,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server5 [08/Feb/2021:00:05:20 -0600] "2.2.2.2 uid=user5,ou=people,ou=employees,dc=company2,dc=com"
```

file3.txt

```
AmLogin server3 [05/Feb/2021:00:01:11 -0600] "22.22.22.22 uid=user2,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server3 [05/Feb/2021:00:01:25 -0600] "33.33.33.33 uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server3 [05/Feb/2021:00:09:25 -0600] "33.33.33.33 uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company"
AmLogin server3 [08/Dec/2020:00:11:44 -0600] "33.33.33.33 uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company" "App1" [0002222000] [0] []
AmLogin server3 [09/Feb/2021:00:07:50 -0600] "33.33.33.33 uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company" "App2" [0003455000] [0] []
```

I wanted to get the recent login with below details for all users, the above shown is just a example file.. We have 100's of huge log files and the data should be pulled out of that.
Please note below, the user2 is mentioned twice, even though the userid shows same they are two different users from different Distinguished Name (DN).  The distinguished name means whole path of a user. example user2 exist from **ou=users,ou=company1,o=company** and another user2 exist in **ou=people,dc=company2,dc=com**. For user4 its under **ou=People,ou=company1,o=company** and for user5 its under **ou=people,ou=employees,dc=company2,dc=com**

Please note some entries (user3) at the end after double quotes have some random text ("App1" [0002222000] [0] []) which can be ignored.

Expected output.txt

```
user1|04/Feb/2021:00:02:30|uid=user1,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company
user2|05/Feb/2021:00:01:11|uid=user2,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company
user2|04/Feb/2021:00:05:20|uid=user2,ou=people,dc=company2,dc=com
user3|09/Feb/2021:00:07:50 -0600|uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company
user4|07/Feb/2021:00:02:30|uid=user4,ou=People,ou=company1,o=company
user5|08/Feb/2021:00:05:20|uid=user5,ou=people,ou=employees,dc=company2,dc=com
```

or without the time if thats going to make it easier.

Expected output.txt

```
user1|04/Feb/2021|uid=user1,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company
user2|05/Feb/2021|uid=user2,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company
user2|04/Feb/2021|uid=user2,ou=people,dc=company2,dc=com
user3|09/Feb/2021|uid=user3,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company
user4|07/Feb/2021|uid=user4,ou=People,ou=company1,o=company
user5|08/Feb/2021|uid=user5,ou=people,ou=employees,dc=company2,dc=com
```

---

Tried to use grep all files with username `$i` and that takes forever:

```
grep $i file*.txt | tail -1
```

Comment: @alecxs not getting the expected result with the above.

Comment: @alecxs the DN i meant full path of the user (Distinguished Name). example user2 exist from ou=users,ou=company1,o=company and another user2 exist in ou=people,dc=company2,dc=com. For user4 its under ou=People,ou=company1,o=company and for user5 its under ou=people,ou=employees,dc=company2,dc=com

Comment: so 'keyword' is the **whole** string (excluding IP address)? *'uid=user5,ou=people,ou=employees,dc=company2,dc=com'*

Comment: guess nobody will help because they think the problem is solved. you should [revise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/367219) your question and add all possible info from comments (63 gb...)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67057/bash-script-optimization-of-processing-speed

Comment: @alecxs thanks for posting

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r user
  do
    for group in users people
      do
        sed -nr "s/.*\[(\S+).*\s(uid=$user,ou=$group,.*)./$user|\1|\2/p" file*.txt | sort -t\| -k2.8nr -k2.4Mr -k2.1nr -k2.13,2.20r | grep -m1 "|uid=$user,ou=$group,"
    done
done < userid.txt
```

---

**Edit:**

if the log files already sorted, iterate over files for every DN and `tail -n1`. the first pass will scan for users and generates another input file `userdn.txt` for second pass

```
#!/bin/sh

# list of users (from logs)
grep -Fiwhf userid.txt file*.txt | grep -io 'uid=[^"]*' | sort --ignore-case -u > userdn.txt

# last login
while read -r user
  do
    grep -Fiwh "$user" file*.txt | tail -n1 | sed -nr 's/.*\[(\S+).*\suid=([^,]+)(.*)./\2|\1|uid=\2\3/p'
done < userdn.txt
```

or via process substitution (bash only)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r user
  do
    grep -Fiwh "$user" file*.txt | tail -n1 | sed -nr 's/.*\[(\S+).*\suid=([^,]+)(.*)./\2|\1|uid=\2\3/p'
done < <(grep -Fiwhf userid.txt file*.txt | grep -io 'uid=[^"]*' | sort --ignore-case -u)
```

---

if log files not sorted and time is more important than disk space, save time by sorting only once in three steps.

-create `userdn.txt`
-sort log files by date into big single file
-iterate over `bigfile.txt` for every DN

```
#!/bin/sh

# list of users (from logs)
grep -Fiwhf userid.txt file*.txt | grep -io 'uid=[^"]*' | sort --ignore-case -u > userdn.txt

# merge log files
grep -Fiwhf userdn.txt file*.txt | sed -nr 's/.*\[(\S+).*\suid=([^,]+)(.*)./\2|\1|uid=\2\3/p' | sort -t\| -k2.8nr -k2.4Mr -k2.1nr -k2.13,2.20r > bigfile.txt

# last login
while read -r user
  do
    grep -Fiwm1 "$user" bigfile.txt
done < userdn.txt
```

---

that is still no good solution because in the end each log is processed multiple times for each user. there must be another solution with `awk` or `join` or `paste` or `uniq` or something.

ideally i would just combine...

```
tac file*.txt | grep -m1 -f userdn.txt
```

... but that won't work for two reasons:
`tac` not working as expected, instead it's serial processing each log one after one.
`-m1` combined with `-f` does not search *all* patterns (from file), instead it stops after *any* pattern.
even if, that would work only for already sorted logs :(

---

What you want is processing log files single pass, read every line, write result into another file, where the write event is realized with a function.

This function should:

-check if DN already exist
-compare date
-update existing entry
-add new entries only

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

# function compare date
compare () {
  [ -n "$2" ] || return 1

  # sort array
  for date in "$@"
    do
      echo "$date"
  done | sort -k1.8n -k1.4M -k1.1n -k1.13,1.20 | tail -n1

  return 0
}

# function write last_login.txt
update () {
  local file=$1 line=$2
  [ -n "$line" ] || return 1

  # string manipulation
  dn=${line#*\"}; dn=${dn%%\"*}; dn=${dn#*+([[:blank:]])}; [ -n "$dn" ] || return 1
  user=${dn%%,*}; user=${user#*=};
  date2=${line#*[}; date2=${date2%%]*}; date2=${date2%+([[:blank:]])*};

  [ -f "$file" ] && date1=$(grep -Fiwm1 "$dn" "$file" | cut -d\| -f2)
  if [ -n "$date1" ]
    then
      # DN already exist
      [ "$date1" = "$date2" ] && return 0
      date=$(compare "$date1" "$date2")
      if [ "$date" != "$date1" ]
        then
          # update existing entry
          sed -i "s;$user|$date1|$dn;$user|$date2|$dn;i" "$file"
      fi
    else
      # add new entries only
      echo "$user|$date2|$dn" >> "$file"
  fi

  return 0
}

# create last_login.txt
for file in file*.txt
  do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    echo "processing $file"
    while read -r line
      do
        update last_login.txt "${line//;/,}"
    done < <(tac "$file")
done

# sort last_login.txt
echo -n "sorting... "
sort -o last_login.txt last_login.txt
echo "finished"

exit 0
```

Comment: thank you so much, looks like I am getting what I was looking for, still testing this with my huge files that's are Gigs in size, taking too long but I feel this is going to get me the expected results.. If you dont mind can you please explain the sed and sort logic used above.

Comment: search for [Sort a set of log files](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) on manpage for example sort by date. sed capturing groups are combined with regex, will explain later

Comment: just realized onething after running the script..I see most of the user entries in the log files are with below DN., searching with the group we may miss lot of entries. But when I looked more deep into it, I would say 90% of the DN entries are similar to below DN(shown for user4 and user5)... really sorry I missed this..

   AmLogin server5 [07/Feb/2021:00:02:30 -0600] "11.11.11.11 uid=user4,ou=People,ou=company1,o=company"

   AmLogin server5 [08/Feb/2021:00:05:20 -0600] "2.2.2.2 uid=user5,ou=people,ou=employees,dc=company2,dc=com"

Comment: the AmLogin start with a next line.. for some reason its not letting me edit my previous update above.. So the user4 and user5 DN is what I am seeing mostly in the logs.. but  now thinking about it if there are other ou structures then we may miss some user entries.. I will update my initial question to include the user4 and user5 as well, i think that should cover 95% of user entry... One of the question you asked above can we get the list of groups.. answer is no because there could be lot like that..

Comment: Log files are not sorted but I am going to try all the three options you gave, will keep you posted..

Comment: @alexcs thanks so much, I am going to test this, will keep you posted.

Comment: @alexcs I ran the script, waited for 5 hours still that was running, I know its sill running in backend because I can see the last_login.txt rolling over with logs. I will wait for it to complete.

Comment: @alexcs the script didn't complete, you are correct lot of i/o on files. I exit the script with ctrl+c.

Comment: the file was 18 Gig

Comment: last_login.txt file had lot of duplicates, one thing I am noticing some entries in input file*.txt at the end had random text after double quotes ", So looks like that was considered as another Distinguished Name... As the logs were too large I didnt notice that. Ideally the entry should stop after double quotes but there were entries that had text.. Exmaple : AmLogin server2 [04/Feb/2021:00:01:09 -0600] "11.11.11.11 uid=user1,ou=users,ou=company1,o=company" **SomeRandomText**

Comment: I have updated the question again, And sure I will mark it as unanswered.

Comment: thanks so much will try and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @alexcs I see the output generating with unique entry now that was good, it was taking too long to complete so I cancelled the script...This is what I found out..my log files are total of 63 Gig in size and each log file has a size of 125 MB, just to test the time taken, I picked only 2 files with 125 MB and ran the script again, it took around 160 minutes for 2 files..

Comment: sorry can't help you, my scripting skills are very limited. maybe it's little faster when using `[[` double square brackets instead of `[` single square brackets for test conditions (bash internal instead of external). last_login.txt file should be cached in memory/array to avoid i/o. creating file in /tmp (tmpfs) might also increase performance. you can post the code on stackoverflow and ask for help on optimizing/parallel processing on all cpu's etc in bash, or even more better in SQL language

Comment: @alexcs sure will do, really appreciate all your help here, but this definitely will help me if I have less log files.