# What are profiling tools available for bash/shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, profiling

I have a project which is entirely written in shell scripts.
I find some of the modules in my code takes a lot of time, I need to reduce it functionality wise.
What are  profiling tools available for shell scripts?

Comment: doubt there are any. guess it's more like try&error https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67057

Comment: Yes, there are lots of methods out there. Start by looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-can-i-profile-a-bash-shell-script-slow-startup and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-can-i-profile-a-bash-shell-script-slow-startup